# Using simple form on ruby on rails, how show required (*) asterisk on nested form label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms, required

I'm using simple_form, haml, and need a label for a group of nested radio buttons to indicate a selection is necessary via an asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

> Required fields are marked with an * prepended to their labels.
>
> By default all inputs are required. When the form object has presence validations attached to its fields, Simple Form tells required and optional fields apart. For performance reasons, this detection is skipped on validations that make use of conditional options, such as :if and :unless.
>
> And of course, the required property of any input can be overwritten as needed:
>
> ```
> <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
>   <%= f.input :name, required: false %>
>   <%= f.input :username %>
>   <%= f.input :password %>
>   <%= f.button :submit %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Comment: The thing is the only input is option buttons, and there is just a text only label. I need the text only label to show an asterisk.

Comment: Uhmm, you can prepend the asterisk manually to the label if it's not related to the form?

Comment: The label is related to the form. Picture a nested form with a label and two radio buttons underneath. How would I add an asterisk (other than manually) using simple_form?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're talking about now. I think it's harder NOT to add an asterisk in simple_form. Show your code, but perhaps read the linked [readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) first.